# Power BI Service connection to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, azure-devops-extensions, serviceconnection

Which is the service connection that I should choose for a power BI connection with Azure DevOps?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The official extension that is provided from Microsoft can be located on the below link.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-pbi-api.pbi-automation-tools

It seems that is the one you choose from the dropdown. There are other extensions also that have been developed by community members and you could also choose one of them depending on your needs.

[image]